# When would I use onCreate in DialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I am wondering when one would use (override) `onCreate` in `DialogFragment` over / in addition to `onCreateDialog`? Couldn't I put everything I can do in `onCreate` in `onCreateDialog`? What about e.g. getting a ViewModel using

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
```

Does it make any difference whether I do this in `onCreate` or in `onCreateDialog`?

Answer (score 0):

Implementations should override this class and implement `Fragment.onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle)` to supply the content of the dialog. Alternatively, they can override `onCreateDialog(android.os.Bundle)` to create an entirely custom dialog, such as an AlertDialog, with its own content
from [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment)

Comment: but what is `onCreate` for then?

Comment: onCreate you should use for Activity but not for Fragments or DialogFragments - check here https://medium.com/@thxall92/activity-fragment-lifecycle-421490ac381b?source=rss-------1

Comment: where in the linked diagram to you see not to use `onCreate`for (Dialog)Fragments?

Comment: it is a common practice. for details - check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment and https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments